# Dep init fails even when package exists

Tags: go, dep

I am trying to package a `go` application using `dep` and when doing `dep init` the below error occours.

I have installed the `amcl` library from here - https://github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/tree/master/version3/go

Even the following packages exists

```
nithin@XPS-L401X:~/go/src/github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN$ ls
ARCH.go  BIG.go  DBIG.go  ECDH.go  ECP2.go  ECP.go  FP12.go  FP2.go  FP4.go  FP.go  MPIN.go  PAIR.go  ROM.go
```

But still i get the following error

```
init failed: unable to solve the dependency graph: Solving failure: No versions of github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl met constraints:
    281d0829b307c911bb2f14f2fedc414a257cb8c8: Could not introduce github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl@281d0829b307c911bb2f14f2fedc414a257cb8c8 due to multiple problematic subpackages:
    Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)  Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)
    master: Could not introduce github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl@master due to multiple problematic subpackages:
    Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)  Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)
    add-js-tests: Could not introduce github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl@add-js-tests due to multiple problematic subpackages:
    Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)  Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)
    fix-retval: Could not introduce github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl@fix-retval due to multiple problematic subpackages:
    Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)  Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)
    milagro-crypto-c: Could not introduce github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl@milagro-crypto-c due to multiple problematic subpackages:
    Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl/FP256BN is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)  Subpackage github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go/amcl is missing. (Package is required by github.com/hyperledger/fabric@release-1.1.)
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Firstly `go get github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl`

Then `cd` into this location (based on your `$GOPATH`) `github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/version3/go`

Follow this instructions to instal `milagro`
https://github.com/milagro-crypto/amcl/tree/master/version3/go

I recommend installing all options one after the other and then don't forget to

`go run TestALL.go`

and

`go run BenchtestALL.go`

else it fails to resolve, idk why.